# Nodejs Multer - Receiving 404 and Cannot Set Headers When Uploading MULTIPLE Files

Tags: node.js, http-status-code-404, multer

I’m receiving a 404 Not Found and "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" when I attempt to submit a form that has two images uploaded. Neither image is a required field, so when I upload one image (can be either) everything works correctly, and I do not get an error. The issue only occurs when I upload both in one request. Checking my uploads folder, when I get a 404, both images are correctly uploaded.

Here is the code for multer:

```
const multerOptions = {
  storage: multer.memoryStorage(),
  fileFilter(req, file, next) {
    const isPhoto = file.mimetype.startsWith('image/');
    if (isPhoto) {
      next(null, true);
    } else {
      next({ message: 'That filetype isn\'t allowed!' }, false);
    }
  },
};

export const upload = multer(multerOptions).fields([
  { name: 'avatar' },
  { name: 'accolade' },
]);

export const resize = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.files) {
    next();
    return;
  }
  Object.keys(req.files).forEach(async (file) => {
    const extension = req.files[file][0].mimetype.split('/')[1];
    req.body[file] = `${uuid.v4()}.${extension}`;
    const uploaded = await jimp.read(req.files[file][0].buffer);
    if (file === 'avatar') {
      await uploaded.resize(300, jimp.AUTO);
    } else if (file === 'accolade') {
      await uploaded.resize(30, jimp.AUTO);
    }
    await uploaded.write(`./public/uploads/${req.body[file]}`);
    next();
  });
};
```

Here is the route:

```
router.post(
  '/team-members/add/:id',
  authController.authCheck,
  userController.isAdmin,
  userController.upload,
  userController.resize,
  userController.validateUser,
  catchErrors(userController.addTeamMember),
);
```

And here are the other middleware methods in the route:

```
export const authCheck = (req, res, next) => {
  (req.isAuthenticated()) ? next() : res.redirect('/login');
};

export const isAdmin = (req, res, next) => {
  (req.user.role !== 'admin') ? res.redirect('/dashboard') : next();
};

export const validateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  req.checkBody('firstName', 'There must be a first name!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('lastName', 'There must be a last name!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'There must be an email!').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('role', 'A role must be specified!').notEmpty();

  const errors = req.validationErrors();
  if (errors) {
    req.flash('error', errors.map(err => err.msg));
    res.redirect('back');
  }
  next();
};
```

And finally the function to add a user (it's wrapped in a function that catches errors rather than catching errors in the controller):

```
export const addTeamMember = async (req, res) => {
  const org = await Org.findOne({ _id: req.params.id });
  if (org) {
    const newUser = new User(req.body);
    newUser.organization = org._id;
    newUser.invitation = true;
    await newUser.save();
    await org.update({ $push: { users: newUser } });

    const inviteLink = `http://${req.headers.host}/join/${org._id}`;
    await send({
      user: newUser,
      filename: 'invitation',
      subject: `Welcome ${newUser.email}`,
      inviteLink,
    });
    req.flash('success', `Yay! An invitation has been sent to ${newUser.email}`);
    res.redirect(`/team-members/${org._id}`);
  } else {
    req.flash('error', 'No organization found!');
    req.redirect('back');
  }
};
```

I only get the error when I upload both an avatar and an accolade in one request. If I upload just one in a single request, I get no errors. In both cases, the image(s) are uploaded to the uploads directory I've specified, the user is added to my db, and an email for an invite is fired off. The redirect on success is a single GET request to a view with the same authCheck and isAdmin middlewares.

I've gone through and commented out the portions of code that are not necessary to submit the request (checkAuth, isAdmin, validateUser, and sending the email) but as long as I upload two in one request I get an error. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer in case this ever trips anyone else up.

The `next()` call is inside the forEach block in the resize method, thus it is being called for each file that is being uploaded. Moving it outside the block (obviously) fixed the issue.